# Send csl file from raspberry to windows

Tags: python, mongodb, raspberry-pi, cloud

I am using raspberry pi to get sensor data as csv files, I wanted to upload these files in mongodb atlas, but the mongodb shell required is +3.4 but the one in raspberry is 2.4.
I thought about a solution, that I send these csv files to windows then import from there.
Is there a command line to send csv file from raspberry to windows using python ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **scp** to copy from raspberry pi machine  to windows machine (if you are using linux distro on raspberry pi)

Comment: I want to use a command line, to add it to my python script !

Comment: you can use scp available in paramiko library for python

Comment: When I do this `scp pi@raspIp:/home/pi/temp1.csv elmou@myip:C:\Users\elmou\Desktop\cloud_project` in the raspberry terminal, it gives me this error : `ssh: connect to host myip port 22: Connection timed out`
But when I run it on windows, it works fine.
Is there any solution for this ?